# .NET Core 2.0 and Aurelia

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, aurelia

Here's my story: I created a solution in VS2017 which contains 3 projects: .NET Core 2.0 dll to store my models, WebAPI (which uses EF Core 2.0 code first) and blank Web Application. In the blank project I would like to create a frontend Aurelia app. So, I did 'au new --here' on that project, selected TypeScript as my transpiler. Now, I have a solution with 3 projects which doesn't build because of:

```
Error   TS5055  Build:Cannot write file 'XX/karma.conf.js' because it would overwrite input file.
```

I updated TypeScript to 2.3 by adding a proper entry to .csproj but still cannot compile my solution in VS2017.

My question is: how to add an Aurelia project to .NET Core 2.0 solution and get "au run --watch" works for it? I followed this post: http://mobilemancer.com/2016/10/19/aurelia-spa-typescript-dotnet-core/ but it seems not to consider all possible scenarios.

Please help me get started with .NET Core 2.0 Aurelia + WebAPI as I've been struggling with that for a couple of days.

Comment: Check your source and destination paths in tsconfig.json

Comment: I recreated the Aurelia project in my solution using Aurelia CLI. I followed tutorials from Aurelia website but there were some steps I had to do additionally to get my app running (installing packages for aurelia-fetch-client separatelly, adding <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked> to csproj). Still, 'au run --watch' is not working for me but I will be trying to develop frontend app with TS & Aurelia anyway. It's quite suprising how many ways of doing so is described online and none of them works without additional googling. Nice school for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the code from `Aurelia-Typescript-Skeleton` from `GitHub` https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/tree/master/skeleton-typescript-aspnetcore

They have created asp.net core application and basic structure for `aurelia` and `typescript`.

You can install SPA Templates from `ASP.NET core 2.0` with CLI command `dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::*`

There you can find reach set of templates to start with `ASP.NET core 2.0`

[image]